# Unable to connect ECONNREFUSED / Unable to connect ENOTFOUND mongo db vsCode

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, virtualbox

I'm trying to connect my mongodb to my vscode and when I try and connect to it using 'mongodb:// it comes up with a connection error. Can anyone help me with this please? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zrmX.png)

Comment: [standard connection string format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format)

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB service?

Answer (score 0):

you need to try this flow to solve your issue. might be it helps you.

1. check mongo service is running or not.
2. if you mongo service is out side of your current machine than you check your IP has access to access your mongo service
3. check your mongo connection URL is correct.
4. try to connect your MongoDB using tools like MongoCompass or Robo 3t.
5. then try in your code for further task